# mysql inserting different value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

```
$insert = mysql_query("
    INSERT into analytics.pagesummary (Date, avg_load_time, min_load_time, max_load_time) 
    VALUES ($date,$string_avg, $string_min,$string_max)" ) 
    or die('PROBLEM'.mysql_error());
```

Actual date values = `'2013-02-07', '2013-02-08', '2013-02-09'`
Date values in the database after the query is fired = `'2004', '2003', '2002'`

Other values being displayed of `avg_load_time`, `min_load_time` & `max_load_time` are correct.

Where are we going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

because the values were not wrap in a single quote and mysql implicitly cast the values silently, it should be

```
INSERT INTO analytics.pagesummary (Date, avg_load_time, min_load_time, max_load_time) 
VALUES ('$date', '$string_avg', '$string_min', '$string_max')
```

The reason why `2013-02-07` when inserted becomes `2004` is because it performs arithmethic operation such that

```
2013 - 02 = 2011 - 07 = 2004
2013 - 02 = 2011 - 08 = 2003
2013 - 02 = 2011 - 09 = 2002
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)